# CSS Scrollable content within flexbox child

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to design layout for single page application. The layout should fill full page height and width without scrolling. Here is layout design:

[image: Layout figure]

All blocks contain a bit of information, all they have fixed height, there is only one block which contains large list of data and it should be scrollable (it is purple on picture).

Currently, I'm using flexible boxes for all UI blocks, but I can't make purple block scrollable. How to make purple block remain flexible (i.e. occupy all available space within blue block), and make its content scrollable (i.e. content should not purple block body).

Maybe there is some better solution (I believe flexible boxes serve a bit another purposes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My goal was not use extra blocks (which easily transform my markup to div-soup), however in this case I had to. The solution is to use CSS's position property, original idea and technical details could be found [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/).
To achieve scrolling content I turned my purple block into a wrapper, it is a child of column oriented flex (blue block) with flex-grow ability set to 1. It occupies all available space within parent. Wrapper is relatively positioned. Inside this block I have another one, having absolute position and sized by `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties. That is the block where content lives, it has `overflow` set to auto.

I have no solution without wrapping.

Here is live demo:

```js
var scrollElem = document.getElementById('scroll');
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.classList.add('item');
    e.innerText = "Content piece";
    scrollElem.appendChild(e);
  }());
}
```

```css
HTML {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
BODY,
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

/*||||*/

#scroll {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#footer {
  height: 30px;
}

/*||||*/

#main {
  background-color: rgb(255, 215, 125);
}
#upper {
  background-color: rgb(170, 215, 125);
}
#bottom {
  background-color: rgb(200, 50, 180);
}
#left {
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0 15px 0 rgba(60, 5, 20, 0.5);
}
#right {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 15px 0 rgba(60, 5, 20, 0.5);
}
#footer {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(60, 5, 20, 0.5);
}
#left,
#right,
#footer {
  color: rgba(60, 5, 20, 0.8);
}

/*||||*/

.D-f {
  display: flex;
}
.A-I-c {
  align-items: center;
}
.F-D-c {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.F-D-r {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.J-C-c {
  justify-content: center;
}
.J-C-sa {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.J-C-sb {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.F-G-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.F-G-2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.F-G-3 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.F-G-4 {
  flex-grow: 4;
}
.F-G-5 {
  flex-grow: 5;
}
.F-W-nw {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.F-W-w {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.Pos {
  position: relative;
}
.Pos-a {
  position: absolute;
}

/*||||*/

#upper,
#bottom {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#upper .popout {
  display: none;
}
#upper:hover .popout {
  display: initial;
}

ASIDE SPAN { font-size : 0.6em; }
```

```html
<div id="main" class="D-f F-D-c J-C-sb">

  <div id="page" class="F-G-1 D-f J-C-sb">

    <aside id="left" class="F-G-3 D-f J-C-c A-I-c">
      Left aside
      <br/>
      <span><sup>3</sup>/<sub>12</sub></span>
    </aside>

    <div id="content" class="F-G-5 D-f F-D-c">

      <div id="upper">
        <h3>Upper block</h3>
        <div class="popout">Ta-Da!</div>
      </div>

      <div id="bottom" class="F-G-1 D-f F-D-c">
        <h3 class="header">Header</h3>
        <div class="misc">Misc</div>
        <div id="scroll-wrap" class="Pos F-G-1">
            <div id="scroll" class="Pos-a"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <aside id="right" class="F-G-2 D-f J-C-c A-I-c">
      Right aside
      <br/>
      <span><sup>2</sup>/<sub>12</sub></span>
    </aside>

  </div>

  <div id="footer" class="D-f A-I-c J-C-c">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your "Purple Box" in css:

```
.purple-box {
    height: 100px; /* Or whatever height you need */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/518h76km/

EDIT: To make it take up any height available, use `calc` with `height:`. For example:

```
.blue-box {
    height: 500px; /* Theoretical height, can be anything */
    padding: 10px; /* You can change this too */
}

.grey-header {
    height: 100px; /* Again, this can be anything */
    padding: 10px; /* ... Same here */
}

.purple-box {
    height: calc(100% - 100px - 20px); /* Subtracts the total height of other elements from the total height of the container, making this element use up the rest of the space left */
}
```

That `calc` is actually calculating the space left in the container. It takes the container's total height - 100% - and then subtracts the heights of the rest of the elements, plus the padding of the parent. Here, it subtracts 20 for the padding of the purple box and 100 for the height of the grey box. You wouldn't usually do `- 100 - 20` but for the sake of clarity that's what I did.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/518h76km/1/

Comment: Your answer is almost the same as previous one (which already disappeared), in this case purple box will always have 100px height, but I want it to be flexible, i.e. purple block should occupy all available space within blue block, but its content should be scrollable.

Comment: I've updated my question with code snippet, please have a look.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used `calc()` before, looks like it is well supported now, I'll and post a feedback. Thanks, George!

Comment: Yeah, `calc()` works wonders for situations like these. Glad I could help! :D

Comment: Finally, I've achieved exactly what I needed with `flexible boxes` and without `calc()`. The idea was found [http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/12/full-height-app-layouts-animated-transitions-within-panes/](here). Notice, upper block contains hidden elements, which when appeared shrinking down bottom puple block (this is reqiured in my app).